# How to play YouTube videos in React native player?

Tags: react-native, youtube, youtube-api

I want to play some YouTube videos in my react native app using a native player as we don't want to show youtube branding in the player. Is there any possible way to do this?
If not, what's the best way to play youtube videos in react native app without showing youtube branding?

Comment: Try this, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57413156/play-youtube-video-in-react-native-video)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using react-native-webview.

```
  <WebView
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    source={{
      uri: `${"YOUR YOUTUBE URL"}?controls=0&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent&rel=0&mode=opaque`,
    }}
    style={{
      height: 200,
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 80,
    }}
    onError={(err) => {
      console.log(err, 'this is errr');
    }}
  />
```

Comment: will this eliminate the Youtube logo and share options from the UI?

Comment: using "modestbranding" you can hide the branding.
please refer https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters